# Weird define in C++ preprocessor

Tags: visual-c++, concatenation, c-preprocessor, stringification

I've come across this

```
#define DsHook(a,b,c) if (!c##_) {  INT_PTR* p=b+*(INT_PTR**)a;  VirtualProtect(&c##_,4,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&no); *(INT_PTR*)&c##_=*p;  VirtualProtect(p,4,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&no);  *p=(INT_PTR)c; }
```

and everything is clear except the "c##_" word, what does that mean?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means to "glue" together, so `c` and `_` get "glued together" to form `c_`. This glueing happens after argument replacement in the macro. See my example:

```
#define glue(a,b) a##_##b

const char *hello_world = "Hello, World!";

int main(int arg, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%s\n", glue(hello,world)); // prints Hello, World!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The gluing happens *before* replacement; if the token before or after the `##` is an argument, it is replaced by the argument, but all other substitutions take place after concatenation.

Comment: I meant before argument substitution in the macro so this won't work: `#define x(a_,c) a##_ + c`.

Answer (score 3):

It is called [a token-pasting operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Example:

```
// preprocessor_token_pasting.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#define paster( n ) printf( "token" #n " = %d", token##n )
int token9 = 9;

int main()
{
   paster(9);
}
```

**Output**

```
token9 = 9
```

Answer (score 2):

That's concatenation that appends an underscore to the name passed as `c`. So when you use

```
DsHook(a,b,Something)
```

that part turns into

```
if (!Something_)
```

Answer (score 2):

After the preprocessor, your macro will be expanded as:

```
if (!c_) {  INT_PTR* p=b+*(INT_PTR**)a;  VirtualProtect(&c_,4,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&no); *(INT_PTR*)&c_=*p;  VirtualProtect(p,4,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&no);  *p=(INT_PTR)c; }
```

The ## directive concatenates the value of c which you pass as a macro parameter to _

Answer (score 1):

Simple one:

```
#define Check(a) if(c##x == 0) { }
```

At call site:

```
int varx; // Note the x
Check(var);
```

Would expand as:

```
if(varx == 0) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called Token Concatenation and it is used to concatenate tokens during the preprocessing
For example the following code will print out the values of the values of c, c_, c_spam:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define DsHook(a,b,c) if (!c##_) \
    {printf("c=%d c_ = %d and c_spam = %d\n",\
    c, c##_,c##_spam);}

int main(){
    int a,b,c=3;
    int c_ = 0, c_spam = 4;

    DsHook(a,b,c);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
c=3 c_ = 0 and c_spam = 4
```